# How to authenticate Firebase to integrate the SDK for cloud storage?

Tags: firebase, sdk, firebase-authentication

I'm statring new with firebase and when authenticating firebase how should I proceed if I want to integrate the SDKs for cloud storage ?

Comment: did you mean authenticate user? or authenticate firebase project with apikey?

Comment: APIkey ! It gives API keys for each firebase right ? It doesn't give any means to supply API key ? and where is it used in the consuming application. Thanks